# Como aplicar estilo para um grupo de seletores

Tags: css

### Contexto

Tenho o seguinte código

```html
<div id="id1"></div>
<div id="id2"></div>
```

Como poderia fazer com que ao passar o mouse em `#div1` e `#div2`, apenas a `#div1` fique com o funde verde?

Comment: Allan, obrigado por sua edição!

Answer (score 0):

Aqui tem um *workaround* com CSS. O pulo do gato é o `column-reverse` aliado ao seletor irmão `~`, no código abaixo segue o exemplo

```css
.container {
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
}

#id1:hover {
    background: green;
}
[id^="id"] {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
[id^="id"]:hover ~ #id1 {
    background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div id="id3">3</div>
    <div id="id2">2</div>
    <div id="id1">1</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sua resposta é mais apropriada que a minha porque não utiliza javascript! Ganhou meu voto, parabéns.

Comment: @RafaelSalomão valeu a força man!

Answer (score 0):

Alternativamente às respostas já apresentadas, pode optar por selecionar apenas o primeiro elemento filho ao passar por cima do seu pai. Algo como:

```css
.container:hover div:first-child {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>AAA</div>
  <div>BBB</div>
  <div>CCC</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Parabéns, bem enxuto o código!